# How can I change code background color when using nbconvert?

Tags: html, jinja2, nbconvert

When converting Jupyter Notebook to html I am trying to change code background color using a Jinja template

```
{% block input_group %}
    <div style="background-color:red;">
        {{ super() }}
    </div>
{% endblock input_group %}
```

When I run nbconvert from comand line, code background color keeps unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You must define a `header` block.

Comment: can you please be more exhaustive? I'm trying to do the same and this answer doesn't help me in the slightest